# How to allocate less memory to Scala with IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, jvm

I'm trying to crash my program (run in IntelliJ) with an `OutOfMemoryException`:

```
  def OOMCrasher(acc: String): String = {
    OOMCrasher(acc + "ADSJKFAKLWJEFLASDAFSDFASDFASERASDFASEASDFASDFASERESFDHFDYJDHJSDGFAERARDSHFDGJGHYTDJKXJCV")
  }
  OOMCrasher("")
```

However, it just runs for a very long time. My suspicions is that it simply takes a very long time to fill up all the gigabytes of memory allocated to the JVM with a string. So I'm looking at how to make IntelliJ allocate less memory to the JVM. Here's what I've tried:

In Run Configurations -> VM options:

```
 --scala.driver.memory 1k || --driver.memory 1k
```

Both of these cause crashes with:

```
Unrecognized option: --scala.driver.memory
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I've also tried to put the options in the Edit Configurations -> Program Arguments. This causes the program to run for a very long time again, not yielding an `OutOfMemoryException`.

EDIT:

I will accept any answer that successfully explains how to allocate less memory to the program, since that is the main question.

UPDATE:

Changing the function to:

```
  def OOMCrasher(acc: HisList[String]): HisList[String] = {
    OOMCrasher(acc.add("Hi again!"))
  }
  OOMCrasher(Cons("Hi again!", Empty))
```

where `HisList` is a simple LinkedList implementation as well as running with `-Xmx3m` caused the wanted exception.

Comment: I think a String has a maximum length, and you will not actually get to an `OutOfMemoryException`.

Comment: @MarkusAppel You can cause an OutOfMemoryError on a really long String, but it has to be upwards of 10,000,000 characters long (in the normal REPL at least - I haven't tried anywhere else). I'm sure if you allocated more memory to it, you could get a longer String.

Comment: For clarity, I didn't test this very thoroughly - just `val d = "d"; d*1000000` then adding 0's until it complained at me ;)

Comment: @JamesWhiteley as far as I am concerned, Scala's `String` class is using Java's `String` class under the hood. And these have a maximum length of `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, because they are actually an array of bytes.

Comment: @JamesWhiteley I just calculated and a `String` of maximum length should top out at about 2.14 GB. So as soon as you give Java more memory than that your aproach no longer works. But correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Sahand see my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To *functionally* reach an `OutOfMemoryException` is harder than it looks, because recursive functions almost always run first into a `StackOverflowException`.

But there is a mutable approach that will guarantee an `OutOfMemoryException`: Doubling a `List` over and over again. Scala's `List`s are not limited by the maximum array size and thus can expand until there is just no more memory left.

Here's an example:

```scala
def explodeList[A](list: List[A]): Unit = {
  var mlist = list

  while(true) {
    mlist = mlist ++ mlist
  }
}
```

To answer your actual question, try to fiddle with the JVM option `-Xmx___m` (e.g. `-Xmx256m`). This defines the maximum heap size the JVM is allowed to allocate.

Comment: Just to clarify: Entering the Edit Configurations -> VM argument `-Xmx3m` allowed me to limit the memory severely and cause an OutOfMemoryError